# React - Build demasiado grande

Tags: javascript, react, build

Estou a desenvolver um site em React com TypeScript. Acontece que antes ao fazer `npm run build`, a pasta `build` gerada tinha uma dimensão aceitável `4mb`, e eventualmente, depois de ter passado de classes para hooks, agora a build tem `30mb`, e a pasta `build/static/js` tem mais de 10000 arquivos `.chunk` e `.chunk.map` ao contrário de antes que só tinha 4! O que é que poderá ter acontecido? Não percebo o porquê.

Answer (score 1):

Muitas vezes quando não se faz a própria otimização, o tamanho da *build* pode crescer bastante, uma vez que todos os arquivos que você está importando são colocados no mesmo *output*, incluindo as suas dependências.

Existem, no entanto, técnicas para contornar esse problema. A mais comum delas é o *code-splitting*, isto é, dividir o seu código em múltiplas partes. [A documentação do React tem uma seção sobre isso.](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)

Você ainda pode usar serviços como o [BundlePhobia](https://bundlephobia.com/), que verifica o tamanho de uma determinada dependência, ou *packages* como o [`webpack-bundle-analyzer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) para verificar o tamanho do seu *bundle*.

---

Por fim, é importante notar que **o tamanho da pasta `build` raramente importa**. O que você deve levar em conta ao desenvolver uma aplicação performática é o tamanho do *bundle* do JavaScript de **cada página**, e não o todo. Lembre-se que no diretório `build` viverão todos os arquivos e dependências da sua aplicação. Desse modo, se você tiver feito o devido *code-splitting*, a sua aplicação provavelmente não sofrerá com problemas de performance causados pelo peso dos arquivos JavaScript.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, adorei o BundlePhobia. A questão é mesmo porque o responsável pelo servidor não consegue fazer deploy da aplicação para a Google Cloud Platform porque o build/static/js tem >1000 ficheiros, e eu não percebo como é que aumentou de 4 para mais de 1000 assim do nada, dado que só passei de classes para hooks e acrescentei o "date-fns" para criar um calendário

Comment: Você nunca deve fazer o build antes do deploy. É aconselhável fazer o build uma vez que os arquivos já estejam no servidor.